# Google Photos doesn't support ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

**TL;DR:** The file picker with `Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` doesn't include Google Photos.

---

I'm trying to get files from the [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider) (SAF) picker, initially I was was using `intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, but that doesn't allow for persistent URIs with `takePersistableUriPermission()`, so I had to switch to `intent.action = Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, but then, this doesn't include a large set of file providers, namely Google Photos and Amazon Drive.

On my device, with `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` the picker only gets local images/downloads and Google drive. With `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` the picker gets these, and all the other file providers I have installed.

**Question:** How do you start the picker, making sure that every file provider is included, and that you're able to get persistent URIs?

My intent if you believe it to be useful:

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.type = "image/*"
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
startActivityForResult(intent, IntentCodes.HOME_GALLERY_INTENT)
```

Comment: "making sure that every file provider is included" -- every provider is included already. The developers of those apps did not implement a `DocumentsProvider`, apparently. That is their decision.

Comment: Very inconvenient

Comment: I won't argue with that. Amazon Drive in particular really needs to support this stuff.